# I'm trying to send this file after compress it using client-compress.js library and catch the information using php. but php saying "undefined file"

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

this code for compress image file and send it using AJAX to the PHP page
and I don't know what's wrong. is there anyone can help me, please
to fix this problem.

I want to compress images on client-side before upload it

```
const options = {
  targetSize: 0.15,
  quality: 0.75,
  maxWidth: 1600,
  maxHeight: 1600
}
const compress = new Compress(options)
const preview = document.getElementById("preview")
const upload = document.getElementById("upload")
upload.addEventListener("change", (evt) => {
    const files = [...evt.target.files]
    compress.compress(files).then((conversions) => {
      const { photo, info } = conversions[0]

    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', photo);
    console.log('fd: ' + fd);
    $.ajax({
        url:'upload.php?name=' + photo.name,
        type:'post',
        data:fd,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(response){
            if(response != 0){
                $(".preview img").attr('src', response);
                $('.preview img').show();
            }else{
                alert('File not uploaded');
            }
        }
    }); 
    })

  },
  false
)
```

this for catching file and upload to dir

```
/* Getting file name */
$filename = $_GET['name'];

/* Location */
$location = "upload/".$filename;
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($location,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

/* Valid extensions */
$valid_extensions = array("jpg","jpeg","png");

/* Check file extension */
if(!in_array(strtolower($imageFileType), $valid_extensions)) {
   $uploadOk = 0;
}

if($uploadOk == 0){
   echo 0;
}else{
   /* Upload file */
   if(copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$location)){
     echo $location;
   }else{
     echo 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details on the PHP error (line etc.).? Also using `move_uploaded_file()` instead of copy makes more sense here. For debugging you can also dump `$_FILES`. Right now it is too much unclear as to provide a solution.

Comment: Blob {size: 144746, type: "image/jpeg"} this is what I sent useng ajax to php